# Application form and fee for Drupal Commerce

Tags: 7, commerce

I am taking application fees for application processing for a real estate broker.  When the user fills out an application, they need to submit payment immediately.

The issue is this isn't really a product.  It's a processing fee.  Am I stuck with using a product?  Can I create an order without the product and just use the fee?  I feel like I should create a line item for an order and do it that way, so the pricing rules flow normally.

When the user is ready to submit their application, I'm going to use the [Drupal NoCart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_nocart) module to take the customer straight to payment.

I haven't been able to find a business case like this online anywhere.

For the new line item type, it looks like I should create a new one:

```
function mymodule_commerce_line_item_type_info() {
    $line_item_types = array();

    $line_item_types['appfee_type'] = array(
        'name' => t('Application Fee'),
        'description' => t('Line item type for app fee.'),
        'product' => FALSE,
        'base' => 'appfee_type'
    );
    return $line_item_types;
}
```

Comment: I'm not using the NoCart module.  It seemed to be relevant to a product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new line item type and adding it to the order was the way to go it seems.  My code is posted in [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/161492/when-checking-out-redirected-to-front-page-and-not-payment-page).

That code worked, however, I kept getting an access denied when trying to check out. DC runs a hook called `hook_commerce_checkout_order_can_checkout()`.  The order is passed to this hook, and you can determine if you want to allow access.  I did on all instances and didn't need to write any logic, so I just returned TRUE, and everything worked.